# Problem in simple MailGun email sending - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, mailgun

I am trying to send simple email through mailgun and laravel, but getting a weird error.
I am not using queue just sending a simple welcome email on run time.

following is error:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Following is mail send code:

```
$details = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    );

 Mail::send('emails.welcome', $details, function ($message) use ($user) {
        $message->from('admin@mywebsite.tv', 'Admin');
        $message->to($user->email);
 });
```

When I comment above code, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you share a link where you got your `Mail::send()` example from?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, this is how you trigger the email:

```
Mail::to("someemail@mail.com")->send(new OrderCreated($order));
```

OrderCreated class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderCreated extends Mailable

{

use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $content;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from(config("mail.mail_from"), "Service Desk")
    ->subject("Order Created")
    ->markdown('emails.order-created')->with('content',$this->content);
}
}
```

mail.mail_from is the blade view which would be used to create email that will be shown to the user.

Comment: Not working in my case, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the use of the closure wrong. This should work:

```
Mail::from('admin@mywebsite.tv', 'Admin')->to($user->email)->send('emails.welcome', $details)
```

Comment: emails.welcome is blade view right?

Comment: @NomanAli Yes. That should be the blade view